# Package does not exist only for some of packages in mainactivity file of the library module

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, module

I searched many times but I could not solve this problem, which is interesting since the error is ONLY due to some of packages in the mainactivity.java file in a library module in the android studio project

I **converted an app to a library module** by these steps (given in https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library);

1) Open the module-level build.gradle file.

2) Delete the line for the applicationId.

3) At the top of the file, write apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

instead of apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Then, **to add the library as a dependency**, I clicked File > New > Import Module

In **settings.gradle** file, I put include ':app', ':my-library-module'
Then, I opened the app module's build.gradle file and add a new line to the dependencies block as

`dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-library-module")
}`

Then, I saved the file and clicked File > Sync Project with Gradle Files.
There is NO error. But, when I click run, it gives error: **package does not exist** (by showing with red color only some of packages in *mainActivity.java* file of the library module)

The red colored words (i.e., unresoved symbols are NonNull, FloatingActionButton, ActivityCompat, Fragment, ContextCompat) in these lines:

- import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
- import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
- import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
- import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
- import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;*

What should be done to solve this problem ?